# socket.io handshaking does not work when using ngrok

Tags: sockets, io, ngrok

Without ngrok, I connectmy client successfullyto the server via the command:

```
socketClient.connect("http://localhost:1337")
```

However, when I use the ngrok generated url:

```
socketClient.connect(" https://ed076d74586e.ngrok.app")
```

I get the output error on the browser console:

```
GET http://%20https/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OW0nMsS net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

with headers:

```
Request URL: http://%20https/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OW0mCEy
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Provisional headers are shown
Learn more
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:50008/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> socketClient.connect(" https://ed076d74586e.ngrok.app")
>                      ^^^
> ```

There is a space after the quote and before the `https`. This space is the problem as can be seen from the error message, which complains about `http://%20https/soc...` - the `%20` is the wrong space.

To fix just delete the space, i.e.

```
 socketClient.connect("https://ed076d74586e.ngrok.app")
```

Comment: OK so your comment about the spaces did the trick. Thans.